# How to force a checkbox and text on the same line?

Tags: html

How can I force a checkbox and following text to appear on the same line? In the following HTML, I'd only want the line to break between label and input, not between input and label.

```
<p><fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b">
    <!-- depending on width, a linebreak can occur here. -->
    <label for="b">b</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">c</label>
</fieldset></p>
```

To clarify: if the fieldset/p is not wide enough for all elements, instead of:

```
[] a [] b []
c [] d [] e
```

I want:

```
[] a [] b
[] c [] d
[] e
```

Comment: why dont you put div between them ?

Comment: I don't know, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: If I wrote a paragraph, e.g. `<p>Hi my name is Andreas</p>`, I wouldn't put linebreaks in there manually, but rather expect the browser to do so. Still, I wouldn't want the browser to insert a linebreak in the middle of `Andreas`, which is what I'm trying to prevent here. That is, I don't know the number of checkbox-label pairs or where the linebreaks will fit beforehand.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It wont break if you wrap each item in a div. Check out my fiddle with the link below. I made the width of the fieldset 125px and made each item 50px wide. You'll see the label and checkbox remain side by side on a new line and don't break.

```
<fieldset>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">a</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <input type="checkbox" id="b">
<!-- depending on width, a linebreak can occur here. -->
    <label for="b">bgf bh fhg fdg hg dg gfh dfgh</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">c</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5dwp7pg/1/

Comment: Try making your label bigger than a single letter ! it will NOT work for longer labels.

Answer (score 32):

Try this CSS:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: A linebreak can still appear between checkbox and label. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: wrap each checkbox and label pair in a div that is set with a display: inline-block

Comment: IE7 doesn't support inline-block

Comment: @Brent: I would vote this up, if only your answer reflected your comment. As it is, the answer, in isolation, is incorrect; but if one does as you suggest in your comment it works.

Answer (score 23):

Try this. 
The following considers checkbox and label as a unique element:

```
<style>
  .item {white-space: nowrap;display:inline  }
</style>
<fieldset>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa a a a a a a aaaaaaaaaaaaa</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <input type="checkbox" id="b">
<!-- depending on width, a linebreak NEVER occurs here. -->
    <label for="b">bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  b b b b  bb</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">ccccc c c c c ccccccccccccccc  cccc</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: 'white-space: nowrap' is the trick I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this solely with css:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Note that this forces each checkbox and its label onto a separate line, rather than only doing so only when there's overflow.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the label around the input:

```
 **<label for="a"><input type="checkbox" id="a">a</label>**
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/etozop/2/edit

```
put a div wrapper with WIDTH :

  <p><fieldset style="width:60px;">
   <div style="border:solid 1px red;width:80px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b">

    <label for="b">b</label>
   </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">c</label>
</fieldset></p>
```

*a name could be " john winston ono lennon" which is very long... so what do you want to do? (youll never know the length)... you could make a function that wraps after x chars like : "john winston o...."*

Comment: This assumes that I knew the p/fieldset size and the length of the labels beforehand.

Comment: @Andreas lets talk extreme , a name could be " john winston ono lennon" which is very long... so what do you want to do ?  you could make a function that wraps after x chars like : "john winston o...."

Comment: A single checkbox-label pair will always fit. I solved it with Brent's comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Set `height: auto` for the input checkbox.

```css
.my-checkbox{
   height: auto;
}
```