# not wrap ListItem Text in Horizontal CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have Dynamic CheckBoxList :

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProjectOrigin.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl_PEM_ASPX_ProjectOrigin" %>
<div style="display:block;">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  >
</asp:CheckBoxList></div>
```

and add  ListItems in my function

```
private void ChkListBoxInit()
    {
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items.Count != 0) return;
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();

        DesProvider p = new DesProvider();
        List<tblDes> list = p.GetByDesGrpId(grpid).OrderBy(a => a.DesId).ToList();
        ListItem li;
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            li = new ListItem(l.DesF, l.val);
        CheckBoxList1.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow;
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(li);
        }
     }
```

The Html generated by this is:

```
<div style="display:block;"> 
  <span id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1">
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$0" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_0">بهبود فرآیند کار</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$1" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_1">بهبود محیط کار</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$2" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_2">ایمنی و بهداشت</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$3" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_3">رفاهی</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$4" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_4">فروش و مشتریان</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$5" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_5">کاهش هزینه ها</label>

    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$ProjectOrigin1$CheckBoxList1$6" />
    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_FormView1_ProjectOrigin1_CheckBoxList1_6">سایر موارد</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

How can i avoid  ListItem text wrapping at end off line and keep checkbox and this text together?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `<label>` elements have the css setting `display: block;`. This should ensure that the label text all stays on the same line.

You can see this in [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaakov/DFrm9/). The example where the labels have `display:inline;` shows the same wrapping that you are seeing. The example where the labels have `display:block;` shows the text staying on the same line.

**Update after html was posted in question**:

Because the `CheckBoxList` is producing `<input>` separate from each related `<label>`, there is no easy way that I can see to keep them in flow, and guarantee that labels do not wrap *and* that labels and checkboxes stay on the same row. You could set `label, input { float: right; display: block; }` in your css, but this would allow labels to be on separate rows from their related inputs.

Best solution that I can see is to not use `CheckBoxList`. Instead, use a `Repeater`, with something like the following for layout:

```
<asp:Repeater id="checkboxes" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="checkboxItem">
      <asp:CheckBox runat=server />
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You would then data bind the repeater in a similar way, populating the value of CheckBox in each `_ItemDataBound` event.

Enclosing each `CheckBox` in a `<div>` and adding `label, .checkboxItem { float: left; }` in your css should force the checkboxes and labels to stay on the same line, per [the technique showed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469906/51).

Comment: I try this but not work, because i have't any lable. i use check Box List

Comment: Please post your html and css

Comment: This Is an UserControl and all of code is in my question, i dont use css, but my Html is <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProjectOrigin.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl_PEM_ASPX_ProjectOrigin" %>
<div style="display:block;">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  >
</asp:CheckBoxList></div>

Comment: I meant to post the html that is generated by this.